# Return node.name if node2.parameter = 0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When you give **someone** x **something** y for some **price** for **ever** - it's called "**sell**". But when you give **someone** x **something** y for some **price** for some **time** - it's called "**rent**". And when it's operation have no **cost** it's called "**present**".

I would like to use neo4j for this operation. But i would not like to create separate sets of nodes for every exchange type, because the point is to show how it is all the same, but name of operation depends on variables parameters - **cost** and **time**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymy2L.png

```
CREATE 
(n:Person { name: "Seller" }),
(b:Person { name: "Buyer" }),
(ntt:Time { name: "Time", forever: 0}),
(nt:Goods { name: "Goods" }),
(nd:Price { name: "Price", zero: 0 }),
(nd2:OperationName { name: "Sell" }),
(nd3:OperationName { name: "Rent" }),
(nd4:OperationName { name: "Gift" }),
(b)-[:sold]->(nt),
(b)-[:rented_out]->(nt),
(b)-[:presented]->(nt) 
RETURN n,b,ntt,nt,nd, nd2, nd3, nd4
```

How to return **OperationName.name: "Gift"** if **Price** is **zero**?

Comment: Could you change the title to something more expressing? Based on it, initially I suspected this post is just a spam. (The rest seems to be mostly ok.)

Comment: yeah, ok. i think last sentence is more appropriate for title

Comment: If goods and buyer are not connected to price, you can't query the price. I think you have to revise your graph model and actually connect Person/Goods/Price to the OperationName nodes.

Comment: just a reminder for future me. http://console.neo4j.org nice alternative to jsfiddle for neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposed simple model. A `Transaction` node has a `price` property and an optional `expires` property, is "provided" by one `Person` and "received" by another, and is associated with a `Goods` item.

Here, I create 2 sample transactions:

```
CREATE
  (a:Person { name: "A" })-[:PROVIDED]->(t:Transaction { price: 13997.95, expires: 1234567})-[:ITEM]->(:Goods { name: "Truck" }),
  (b:Person { name: "B" })-[:RECEIVED]->(t),
  (b)-[:PROVIDED]->(t2:Transaction { price: 0 })-[:ITEM]->(:Goods { name: "Candy" }),
  (c:Person { name: "C" })-[:RECEIVED]->(t2);
```

And here I dump out information about all the transactions -- including if it is a present (versus a purchase) and if it is a rental:

```
MATCH
  (provider:Person) -[:PROVIDED]-> (t:Transaction) -[:ITEM]-> (goods:Goods), 
  (receiver:Person) -[:RECEIVED]-> (t)
RETURN
  t.price = 0 AS isPresent, t.expires IS NOT NULL AS isRental, provider.name, receiver.name, t.price, goods.name, t.expires;
```

Here are the results:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| isPresent | isRental | provider.name | receiver.name | t.price  | goods.name | t.expires |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| false     | true     | "A"           | "B"           | 13997.95 | "Truck"    | 1234567   |
| true      | false    | "B"           | "C"           | 0        | "Candy"    |           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=m8pow8).

Comment: it's incredible. you have an amazing mind and experience in cypher!) thank you.